# Rpsec rake aborted! Load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I'm trying to run Test First Ruby (a Ruby tutorial from http://testfirst.org/). I have to complete the exercises as part of an assignment.

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 and rspec (which it requires). But when I try running "rake" from the command line window, I get an error message:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) - did find: [rspec-3.0.0]
C:/Users/Motiur/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/Rakefile:2:in '<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When running with trace as it suggested:

```
C:\Users\Motiur\Desktop\test-first-ruby-master\00_hello>rake --trace
(in C:/Users/Motiur/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master)
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) - did find: [rspec-3.0.0]
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
C:/Users/Motiur/Desktop/test-first-ruby-master/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:i
n `load'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:i
n `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:
in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:i
n `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:
in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:i
n `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:i
n `block in run'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:
in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:i
n `run'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried reinstalling Ruby & Rspec, and I even tried on two different computers but I got the same error. Maybe I'm installing it incorrectly? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Before running `rake`, you should run `bundle install`. This only needs to be done once. If you get command not found when running `bundle`, install the bundler gem. This can be done with `gem install bundler`.

For your information, `bundle` is a command from the bundler gem. In ruby, gems are packages. They usually contain libraries, but sometimes they contain tools and other nifty things. Bundler is used to manage dependencies.

To use bundler, you have to write a Gemfile (an actual file named Gemfile that you put in the root of your application). This Gemfile defines all the gems that are required by your app. When you run `bundle install`, it looks at the Gemfile and installs all the gems that it needs.

From what I understand, the tutorial you are following already comes with a Gemfile. All you need to do is run `bundle install`.